# Converting a wrong date into the correct format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a wrong date in the database 2022-10-14 12:59:00 , I want to change it to 2022-14-10 12:59:00. Is there a direct convert function I could use, or do I have to split and put the date correctly. Just trying to get some ideas to do this the easy way. I tried the convert functions but I guess the original date as to be corrected first is it?

Comment: What happens when you execute the query `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), <<youcolumn>>) from <<yourtable>>`? Does it show the correct Date and month ?

Comment: Please read the rules for the [tag:sql] tag: you must additionally tag with the specific engine, especially given that date handling in different engines is done in very different ways.

Comment: the above shows Oct 14 2022 12:29PM, when I run the convert above

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format; this is something for your presentation layer. That has _nothing_ to do with SQL Server. If your data is being stored in a [date and time data type](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql#DateandTimeDataTypes) the value is correct; if you want it **_displayed_** in a certain format, that is a setting you need to configure in the application your users are using. If your data _isn't_ stored as a date and time data type (such as a `varchar`), you have a design flaw that needs fixing.

Comment: What data type *is* your column?

Comment: I am not aware of any date format with the order year-day-month, so - assuming ISO-8601 order as used by the SQL standard - 2022-14-10 is not a valid date, while 2022-10-14 is a valid date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CONVERT() function to go from a date type to a string with a particular "style".  There are styles for different presentation formats to represent the different date presentation formats around the world.

To make this work, the data needs to be in a date type, not just a string.  (or you can convert from a string type to a date type, then convert back to a string).

[Date style descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)